# How can I copy images into a table using jQuery Draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, frontend

I have a list of images, and an empty table

I need to be able to drag an image over to an empty table cell and have that image be copied (not moved) into the new cell.

Sortable almost took care of this for me, but it wont replace the existing cell.

Here is the demo of what I am currently working on: http://simonwjackson.com/demos/bti/demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jqueryui, you can set a property on your draggable item to make it clone instead of move.

```
$(".items").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```